# Which function in a ”honeypot” contract prevents buyers from selling their tokens?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, binance-smart-chain, binance-chain

A common scam in the world of Binance Smart Chain tokens is to launch a new token/contract that to the average person looks enticing, but when buyers purchase the tokens, they soon find that they are unable to sell them, and thus have lost their money.

I have heard it said that the developers of the token accomplish this by “blacklisting” all other wallets except their own from selling, but I am not sure how accurate (or how literal vs euphemistic) that explanation is.

Some people try to avoid this type of scam by making a test purchase/sale of a negligible amount to make sure the tokens is able to be sold.

My question is: **are there particular functions/settings in the contract that could be scanned for and checked to identify whether or not a coin is this type of scam**, instead of having to make a test purchase to find out?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

if owner set *swapandliquify* to *false*  all the swaps could be locked. some people reported that scammers are using *uniswapv2pair* same way.

compiler version 0.5.17 has a lot of exploits/bugs too.

we at cointutu have an everyday challenge fighting against BSC scams.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.